# how to add the option scaling to the tcp packet with scapy

Tags: python, linux, tcp, scapy

my tcp packet is:

```
SYN=IP(dst=dest)/TCP(sport=sp, dport=dp, flags="S", window=65535)
```

I want to add the option window scaling to my TCP packet in that way:

[image]

How I can do that with scapy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `scapy/layers/inet.py` there is a list of TCP options that may be added to the packet:

```
TCPOptions = (
              { 0 : ("EOL",None),
                1 : ("NOP",None),
                2 : ("MSS","!H"),
                3 : ("WScale","!B"),
                4 : ("SAckOK",None),
                5 : ("SAck","!"),
                8 : ("Timestamp","!II"),
                14 : ("AltChkSum","!BH"),
                15 : ("AltChkSumOpt",None),
                25 : ("Mood","!p")
                },
              { "EOL":0,
                "NOP":1,
                "MSS":2,
                "WScale":3,
                "SAckOK":4,
                "SAck":5,
                "Timestamp":8,
                "AltChkSum":14,
                "AltChkSumOpt":15,
                "Mood":25
                } )
```

Example of a packet with added `window scale` option `WScale`:

```
x=Ether()/IP()/TCP(sport=sp, dport=dp, options=[('WScale', 100)])
```

Wireshark correctly recognizes the option.